# negation of powersets

Tags: logic

If given two power sets P(A) and P(B), and told that the Union of these two sets was a subset of another powerset P(C), what would be the negation of this statement? Would the Union go to an intersect, or would the subset be the only part of the logical statement to change?

Comment: The union of the powerset of two sets is a subset of the powerset of the union of the two sets.

Answer (score 2):

A negation of $$\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subset \mathcal{P}(C)$$ is  $$\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \not \subset \mathcal{P}(C)$$

Answer (score 0):

The statements $\wp\left(A\right)\subseteq\wp\left(C\right)$ and
$A\subseteq C$ are equivalent. So:

$\neg\left(\wp\left(A\right)\cup\wp\left(B\right)\right)\subseteq\wp\left(C\right)\iff\neg\wp\left(A\right)\subseteq\wp\left(C\right)\vee\neg\wp\left(B\right)\subseteq\wp\left(C\right)\iff\neg A\subseteq C\vee\neg B\subseteq C\iff\neg A\cup B\subseteq C$